# Can't find solution to Calculus 8th (Adams, Essex) limit problem

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms, transcendental-equations

I've been sitting here for hours trying to find a solution to his problem:

> If you have the function $g(y)$, which is the inverse of 
>   $$f(x) = x^x\\ e^{-1} \leq x < \infty,$$
>   Show that
>   $$\lim\limits_{y \to \infty} \dfrac{g(y) \ln (\ln y)}{\ln y} = 1$$

**Hint:** Start with the equation $y=x^x$ and take the ln of both sides twice.

Comment: If you replace $y$ by $x^x$ in the expression, can you see how to simplify it?

Comment: How far did you get with the hint?

Comment: I didn't get very far with the hint, besides $\ln \ln y = \ln x + \ln \ln x$.

Comment: If I follow your advice @Daniel, I get this: $\lim_{x^x \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{\ln \ln x}{\ln x} \right)$ And I'm not really sure on how to proceed from that...

Comment: If you don't see it in that form, maybe writing $u = \ln x$ helps.

Comment: Well yes, as I know that as $x^x \to \infty \Rightarrow x \to \infty$, and as ln x grows faster than ln ln x $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln x}{\ln \ln x} = 0$.

Comment: Oh but maybe that completes the proof?

Answer (score 1):

If we let that $y = x^x$ then $g(y) = x$ because that $g(x^x) = x$ by the definition of the problem. Then if we use the hint given by the problem

$$\ln(y) = x\ln(x)$$

So, for $e^{-1} \leq x < \infty \implies 0< e^{-x} \leq x^x < \infty$ we have that $0 <  y < \infty$  so take $x > 1$ then

$$\lim_{y \to +\infty}\frac{g(y)\ln(\ln(y))}{\ln(y)} = \lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{x\ln(x\ln(x))}{x\ln(x)} = \lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{\ln(x\ln(x))}{\ln(x)} = \lim_{x \to +\infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{\ln(x)}\right) = \color{red}{1}$$

Because $\ln$ is a crescent - and not bounded above - function we used that

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{1}{\ln(x)} = 0$$